# Safari crash and refusal/failure to reload

Tags: safari

Recently, Safari unexpected crashed while I was using my desktop.  Now, when I try to reload, it keeps saying it "unexpectedly quit" and will not reload (even when I push the reload button).  I have restarted my computer multiple times but it will not open Safari and I keep getting the same error messages over and over.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1st thing to try is go to ~/Library/Safari/ & move the contents of the Extensions folder somewhere else.
Try again.
If successful, quit, add back one at a time, restarting Safari between each to eliminate which one was responsible.

Alternatively, go to ~/Library/Saved Application State/ & delete the entire folder called com.apple.Safari.savedState